# How to specialize a complex template with inheritance - C++

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, partial-specialization

I can't seem to find the right syntax to specialize this template :

```
template <class Object, class Var, class Invert, class Step = Var, unsigned int FIXED = IW_GEOM_POINT>
class TSin : public BasicTween<Object, Var> {...
```

I want to keep `<Object>` as a template parameter but specialize all other parameters. I am trying it like this :

```
    template <class Object>
class TSin<Object, CIwVec2, int, CIwVec2, IW_GEOM_POINT> {...
```

This gives errors.

Please can someone provide the right syntax to specialize the template and the syntax to instantiate the specialized version?

Comment: What's your compiler? Also, make a minimal complete example that reproduces the error. Your description and syntax look fine so far

Comment: Your code as it stands (for the partial specialization) is fine. Most likely the problem is happening where you are trying to use this specialization - may be post a snippet of that?

Comment: You need to provide the error, your code looks fine.

Comment: You were right. I had problem with make an instant of the specialization.

The most elegant solution was to make a subclass of the initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is you're redefining `class TSin`. I don't think you can do that.

What you *can* do is declare the generic template and specialize the definitions of the class:

```
template <class Object, class Var, class Invert, class Step = Var, 
    unsigned int FIXED = IW_GEOM_POINT>
    class TSin;
template <class Object>
    class TSin<Object, CIwVec2, int, CIwVec2, IW_GEOM_POINT> {...
```

or specialize the definitions of members of the class:

```
template <class Object>
void TSin<Object, CIwVec2, int, CIwVec2, IW_GEOM_POINT>::Foo(...) {...
```

or declare a subclass:

```
template <class Object, class Var, class Invert, class Step = Var, 
    unsigned int FIXED = IW_GEOM_POINT>
    class TSin : public BasicTween<Object, Var> {...
template <class Object>
    class SpecialTSin::public TSin<Object, CIwVec2, int, CIwVec2, IW_GEOM_POINT>
{...
```

I think the latter option is the best.

Comment: He isn't redefining TSin. He's doing a partial specialization (your option 1)

Comment: You absolutely can do that. The original definition serves as an unspecialized base case.

Comment: @DeadMG: How could that work, though? If a given set of template parameters could resolve to a base *definition* or a specialized *definition*, which gets used? What if there are overlapping specializations? What if a specialization is visible to one compilation unit and not others? It just looks like a recipe for pain.

Comment: Method 2 is wrong - you can't partially specialize the definitions of members of the class (it will cause compilation error).

Comment: Even if you declare the member function as a template itself?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should look like here: http://ideone.com/cvGy3

You need to define all types for class instantiation.